# SQL statment works in phpMyAdmin but not PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo

I Have a SQL query that uses PHP/PDO. I am using a left join. If I copy/paste the echoed SQL in phpMyAdmin Results come up just fine. But I get a PDO Exception in PHP. I have a Class with Static Variables for my Table and Column Names called DBMGR. The Exact Error I am getting is below. I know my SQL Class works because I have other SQL code going though the same class and functions good.

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table
>   'DBs' in field list' in /usr/share/nginx/html/Library/SQL.class.php:86
>   Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/html/Library/SQL.class.php(86):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/Library/SQL.class.php(90): SQL::Execute() #2
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/Library/Actions/API/ListDatabases.php(23):
>   SQL::Results() #3 /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php(43):
>   include('/usr/share/ngin...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/Library/SQL.class.php on line 86"

My PHP:

```
echo $sql = "SELECT `" . DBMGR::$database_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$database_db_db_id . "`, `" . DBMGR::$database_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$database_db_description . "`, `" . DBMGR::$database_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$database_db_icon . "`, `" . DBMGR::$database_db . "`.`" , DBMGR::$database_db_name . "`, `" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$permissions_db_id . "`, `" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "`.`" , DBMGR::$permissions_db_level . "`, `" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$permissions_db_user_id . "` FROM `" . DBMGR::$main_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$database_db . "` LEFT JOIN `" . DBMGR::$main_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "` ON  `" . DBMGR::$database_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$database_db_db_id . "` = `" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$permissions_db_id . "` AND `" . DBMGR::$permissions_db . "`.`" . DBMGR::$permissions_db_user_id . "` = '1';";

SQL::Query($sql);
$result = SQL::Results();
```

Comment: Provide SQL that is echoed and contents of SQL::Query() method.

Comment: SELECT `DBs`.`DB_ID`, `DBs`.`DB_Description`, `DBs`.`DB_Icon`, `DBs`.`DB_Name`, `Permissions`.`Permission_DB_ID`, `Permissions`.`Permission_Level`, `Permissions`.`Permission_User_ID` FROM `dbmgr`.`DBs` LEFT JOIN `dbmgr`.`Permissions` ON `DBs`.`DB_ID` = `Permissions`.`Permission_DB_ID` AND `Permissions`.`Permission_User_ID` = '1';

Comment: Maybe you have selected the wrong database in your PHP code?